# Is there an event raised when forms authentication expires?

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I have a ASP.Net website that uses Forms Authentication, when a user logs in, it takes up a license for that specific user.  When they sign-out, it frees up the license.

But if the user closes their browser without logging-out I can't really capture that.

So I was wondering if when their session expires, is there an event raised that would allow me to run my code to free up my license?

I thought about having a check in the login page that if it has been re-directed (because they are no-longer authenticated), but I won't know who the user was and I need their details to release their license.

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices, either call web-method from [onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) and put your logic there or use `Session_End` event of `Global.asax` file and put your logic there. Make sure you are using in-proc session while using `Global.asax`

**Edit** Try storing something in `Session` in `Session_Start` if `Session_End` is not called. Something like

Session["dscd"] = "sdcsd";

Comment: Thanks for the info.  So the Session_End would be the ideal place.  So created a sub in my Global.asax  called Session_End as it was not shown in the drop down list of events.  But it does not seem to get called.  I created a Session_Start which does get called.  I know this is a separate issue as a few others have hit it, but fixed it with <sessionState mode="InProc"> but that's not working for me, any ideas?

Comment: If you add global.asax in your file then `Session_End` should automatically be added there. You don't have to do it. I think you created `Global.asax` by your self? If so, then please remove it and add it with `Add New Item` option and check if debugger hits it.

Comment: You're right I did create the global.asax myself (old habits), so did as suggested and Add New Item and it is there now, but still does not seem to get caught by the debugger.

Comment: nope still won't hit it.  It does hit the Session_Start though so I figure it's working partially.  I've set my timeout = 1.  Then I've logged in with forms authentication, then left the screen for 3 or 4 mins, no breakpoint is hit, then as soon as I click on anything I get my login screen again so the session has expired.

Comment: I think I've figured out what is happening, I left my machine in debug for an hour for lunch & when I cam back it had hit the breakpoint, so it looks like although I set the timeout="1" it is still defaulting to 30 minutes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93817/discussion-between-sbarnby71-and-imad).